# file path shortener c#

Tags: c#, file-io, path

So I am using the StreamReader class, and in the spot where my address goes I have  @"S:\Temporary Shared Space\Project\Boyscout3\Data\full_pack.txt" My colleague believes that instead of typing out that super long filename there is a short way of getting it done. My colleague believes that you can just put in @"full_pack.txt*" and it will look for all file names in your computer that has that name. Is my colleague crazy or is this an actual thing?

Comment: You could just answer your own question by trying it and seeing.

Comment: He is crazy, simple as that. It would however look in the current working directory.

Comment: If you use `@"full_pack.txt*"` it will read `full_pack.txt*` (an invalid file) from the current *working directory.*

Comment: It sounds like he's thinking of globbing from Linux shells.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based because your colleague's sanity is a matter of opinion and I doubt most of us are qualified to determine if he is crazy or just misguided.

Comment: @SLaks that is what I told him and he swears up and down that its the same in .Net stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> My colleague believes that instead of typing out that super long filename there is a short way of getting it done.

It depends on what context you are executing the program in. You can use a relative path to make the string shorter (and more flexible).

> My colleague believes that you can just put in @"full_pack.txt*" and it will look for all file names in your computer that has that name.

I don't know why you added a `*` but unless you are using a search method you will need to remove that character. `"full_pack.txt"` that will grab `full_pack.txt` from the current directory, wherever that is.